# Conditional formatting of percentages using Icon Sets

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2013, conditional-formatting

I have a column with percentages, for example

```
+------+
| -19% |
|  17% |
|   4% |
|  30% |
| -31% |
```

I'm trying to use the Icon Set green, yellow and red. For a negative percentage, I would like to use the Red Icon. Any percent above 90 should use the Yellow one. Below 90 percent it has to be the Green Icon.

I tried changing several conditions in the rules for the conditional formatting but I wasn't successful.

Comment: It depends of Excel if you have Excel-2010 and more you can do it by customizing the set but for Excel 2007 you have to use the available colors and sequences Red, Yellow, Green [Customize Excel Icon Set](http://blog.contextures.com/archives/2011/05/16/customize-excel-conditional-formatting-icons/)

Comment: I have excel 2013. I haven't been able to customize it to show the colors based on the way I mentioned. Do you know how to make it work?

Comment: Follow the link Customize Excel Icon Set

Comment: Can you use a second column to create the icon set

Comment: What formula(s) have you tried?

Comment: I figured it out. I changed the value to number instead of percentage and used >=0.9  as yellow, <0.9 as green, <0 as red. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Changed the second "Type" to 'Number' instead of 'Percent'

[image]

Modified answer from the comments.  Posted as community wiki.